# How to calculate values according to the a value's nth occurances in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = ['Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan']
df['Date'] = ['2014-10-07', '2015-03-30', '2015-12-07', '2015-12-09', '2017-01-30', '2017-01-30', '2018-02-19', '2018-02-23', '2018-11-19', '2020-01-23']
df['Value'] = [2200, 75, 100, 22, 98, 0.36, 57, 29, 1026, 1296]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

```
    Name    Date    Value
0   Ankita  2014-10-07  2200.00
1   Ankita  2015-03-30  75.00
2   Ankita  2015-12-07  100.00
3   Ankita  2015-12-09  22.00
4   Ankita  2017-01-30  98.00
5   Yashvardhan 2017-01-30  0.36
6   Yashvardhan 2018-02-19  57.00
7   Yashvardhan 2018-02-23  29.00
8   Yashvardhan 2018-11-19  1026.00
9   Yashvardhan 2020-01-23  1296.00
```

How can I calculate the average `Value` of only the earliest 3 entries of Ankita (expecting to be 791.67) and Yashvardhan (expecting to be 28.79)? And how can I calculate the average value of only the 4th and 5th earliest entries for Ankita (expecting to be 60) and Yashvardhan (expecting to be 1161)?

I tried some manipulations with `value_counts()`, but I couldn't figure it out. Does anyone know the answer to such a problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this with boolean indexing and the groupby/transform function: .rank()

For your first case, the mean of the earliest 3 entries per person:

To get the rows you want:

```
In [23]: dfg = df[df.groupby('Name')['Date'].rank(ascending=True) <= 3]

In [24]: dfg
Out[24]:
          Name       Date    Value
0       Ankita 2014-10-07  2200.00
1       Ankita 2015-03-30    75.00
2       Ankita 2015-12-07   100.00
5  Yashvardhan 2017-01-30     0.36
6  Yashvardhan 2018-02-19    57.00
7  Yashvardhan 2018-02-23    29.00
```

To then get the means of the 'Value' column per person:

```
In [28]: dfg.groupby('Name')['Value'].mean()
Out[28]:
Name
Ankita         791.666667
Yashvardhan     28.786667
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

The rank values could be given as a list for specific values rather than the comparison, and these could be chained together in a one-liner as well:

```
In [29]: df[df.groupby('Name')['Date'].rank() <= 3].groupby('Name')['Value'].mean()
Out[29]:
Name
Ankita         791.666667
Yashvardhan     28.786667
Name: Value, dtype: float64

In [30]: df[df.groupby('Name')['Date'].rank().isin([4,5])].groupby('Name')['Value'].mean()
Out[30]:
Name
Ankita           60.0
Yashvardhan    1161.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```